# Grails 2.2 to 2.3 - jersey jaxrs plugin dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: maven, jersey, jax-rs, grails-2.2, grails-2.3

I'm migrating my project from grails 2.2 to 2.3 and everything work fine except jaxrs plugin

My BuildConfig.groovy looks like:

```
...
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    plugins {
        compile ':jaxrs:0.8'
    }
}
```

I got this error message:

```
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.restlet.gae:org.restlet.ext.json:jar:2.0.0, org.restlet.gae:org.restlet:jar:2.0.0, org.restlet.gae:org.restlet.ext.servlet:jar:2.0.0: Could not find artifact org.restlet.gae:org.restlet.ext.json:jar:2.0.0 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.restlet.gae:org.restlet.ext.json:jar:2.0.0, org.restlet.gae:org.restlet:jar:2.0.0, org.restlet.gae:org.restlet.ext.servlet:jar:2.0.0: Could not find artifact org.restlet.gae:org.restlet.ext.json:jar:2.0.0 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.restlet.gae:org.restlet.ext.json:jar:2.0.0, org.restlet.gae:org.restlet:jar:2.0.0, org.restlet.gae:org.restlet.ext.servlet:jar:2.0.0: Could not find artifact org.restlet.gae:org.restlet.ext.json:jar:2.0.0 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.restlet.gae:org.restlet.ext.json:jar:2.0.0, org.restlet.gae:org.restlet:jar:2.0.0, org.restlet.gae:org.restlet.ext.servlet:jar:2.0.0: Could not find artifact org.restlet.gae:org.restlet.ext.json:jar:2.0.0 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
| Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

When I run the report, I got:

```
+--- org.grails.plugins:jaxrs:0.8
|    >>>> org.restlet.gae:org.restlet.ext.json:2.0.0
|    >>>> org.restlet.gae:org.restlet:2.0.0
|    \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.14
|    \--- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1
|    \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:1.14
|    >>>> org.restlet.gae:org.restlet.ext.servlet:2.0.0
|    \--- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-spring:1.14
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.0.RC3
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-asm:3.0.0.RC3
|              \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.0.0.RC3
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.0.RC3
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:3.0.0.RC3
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.0.0.RC3
|    \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.14
|    \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.14
|    \--- asm:asm:3.3
|    \--- org.spockframework:spock-grails-support:0.7-groovy-2.0
|    \--- org.grails.plugins:spock:0.7
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grails-jaxrs-discuss/KAiJW6Yhkv0). There's a beta version being develop.

I've done what is suggested:

I added the mavenRepo

```
mavenRepo 'https://noams.artifactoryonline.com/noams/grails-jaxrs-plugin-snapshots'
```

And as I use the new Aether (Maven) resolver I configure the jaxrs plugin like this:

```
compile (':jaxrs:0.10-SNAPSHOT') {
    excludes 'spring-core', 'spring-beans', 'spring-context', 'spring-web', 'spring-aop'
}
```

But org.restlet.ext.json:jar:2.1.4 was still missing so I also have to add this mavenRepo:

```
mavenRepo 'http://maven.restlet.org'
```

Application cleaned! Tests Passed!

Comment: Thank you just adding the following two repos solved it for me:         mavenRepo 'https://noams.artifactoryonline.com/noams/grails-jaxrs-plugin-snapshots'
        mavenRepo 'http://maven.restlet.org'

Comment: Hi I tried above solution and it doesn't work for me.. also link provided for repo  https://noams.artifactoryonline.com/noams/grails-jaxrs-plugin-snapshots'   is throwing error                                                      {
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "/noams/grails-jaxrs-plugin-snapshots'"
  } ]
}

Comment: Look here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grails-jaxrs-discuss/KAiJW6Yhkv0 for more info